# Python Dataframe table manipulation

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| Account | Effective_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-Jan-2022 |
| 1 | 10-Jan-2022 |
| 1 | 21-Jan-2022 |
| 2 | 05-Jan-2022 |
| 2 | 21-Jan-2022 |
| 3 | 10-Jan-2022 |
| 4 | 01-Jan-2022 |
| 4 | 10-Jan-2022 |
| 5 | 01-Jan-2022 |
| 5 | 02-Jan-2022 |
| 5 | 03-Jan-2022 |
| 5 | 04-Jan-2022 |

The max Account# can repeat is 4. I want to change it to a table to something like this

| Account | Effective_Date | Effective_Date1 | Effective_Date2 | Effective_Date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-Jan-2022 | 10-Jan-2022 | 21-Jan-2022 |  |
| 2 | 05-Jan-2022 | 21-Jan-2022 |  |  |
| 3 | 10-Jan-2022 |  |  |  |
| 4 | 01-Jan-2022 | 10-Jan-2022 |  |  |
| 5 | 01-Jan-2022 | 02-Jan-2022 | 03-Jan-2022 | 04-Jan-2022 |

The transformed table has unique columns, the repeated row value gets added to the column.

Appreciate if someone can give me a python snippet for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you didn't know your columns `Effective_Date1`, `Effective_Date2`, `Effective_Date3`, `Effective_Date4`. But this is a job for `pivot`:

```py
df['Rank'] = df.groupby('Account').cumcount()
result = df.pivot(index='Account', columns='Rank')
result.columns = [f'{i}{"" if j == 0 else j}' for i, j in result.columns.to_flat_index()]

result = result.reset_index().fillna('')
```